Question in Davis' Applied Nonstandard Analysis
I am struggling over a proof in Davis' Applied Nonstandard Analysis book: Chapter 1, Section 4, Lemma 5 (page 18).
Background:

$N=\lbrace 0,1,2,3,... \rbrace$
$S_0=S$ (set of individuals)
$S_{i+1}=S_i\cup\mathscr{P}(S_{i})$
$\hat S = \bigcup_{i\in N}S_i$ (superstructure / standard universe)
With some index set $I$ and an ultrafilter $F$ on $I$, we define an associated measure $\mu_F(A)=1$ if $A\in F$ and $\mu_F(A)=0$ otherwise. A property holds "a.e." if it holds on a set of measure 1 (or equivalently, if the set for which it doesn't hold has measure 0).
For $n\in N$, $Z_n$ is the set of all functions mapping $I$ into $\hat S$ for which $f_\delta\in S_n$ a.e.
$Z=\bigcup_{n\in N}Z_n$
For $f,g\in Z_0$, we have the equivalence relation $f\sim g$ if $f_\delta = g_\delta$ a.e.
For each $f\in Z_0$, $\overline f = \lbrace g\in Z_0| g\sim f \rbrace$
For $f\in Z_{i+1}-Z_i$, we define $\overline f$ to be the set of all $\overline g$ such that $g\in Z_i$ and $g_\delta\in f_\delta$ a.e.

My Question:
So Lemma 5 states: "If $f,g\in Z$ and $\overline f\subseteq \overline g$, then $f_\delta\subseteq g_\delta$ a.e."
The very first line in the proof is where I am stumped: "Since $\overline f$, $\overline g$ are sets, [we have] $f,g\notin Z_0$." This is confusing since no matter which $Z_i$ that $f,g$ belong to ($i=0$ vs $i\ne 0$), $\overline f$, $\overline g$ are defined as sets, so I'm not sure how we conclude anything from the fact that they are sets.
I thought outside the box that maybe he is just skipping the proof of the $f,g\in Z_0$ case, but even then, if $f,g\in Z_0$, then $f_\delta,g_\delta$ are individuals (in S) so they aren't sets. So we do need to conclude somehow that $f,g\notin Z_0$ for the assertion in the lemma to make sense.
What am I missing? I have been pleased with the rigor of this book so far, but I'm falling short here.

Maybe they meant $\overline f,\overline g\not\in Z_0?$

I think we really need $f,g\notin Z_0$ because the next sentence in the proof is to "Let $A=\lbrace \delta\in I| f_\delta \subseteq g_\delta \rbrace$", and $f,g\notin Z_0$ is what would allow us to say that $f_\delta,g_\delta$ are not individuals (in S) but actually sets themselves so that we can talk about subset relations between them.

Oh, I misread the definition of $\overline f$ for the non-zero case.

I thought the same thing you said at one point, how $f_\delta=g_\delta$ a.e. would certainly mean $f_\delta\subseteq g_\delta$ a.e., but again this would only be true if $f_\delta,g_\delta$ are known a priori to be sets. For example $2=2$, but $2\subseteq 2$ doesn't seem to make sense.

Actually, the preface to the book mentions errata on page 183, and there he gives a lot of material that is meant to replace a large chunk of the material that contains the lemma I am troubling over. So I believe my issue has already been solved by the author.

Goldblatt does  a pretty good job with the ultrapower construction also (including universes starting in chapter 13), so you may want to check out his book as well.
